# How to reduce the size of the AppBarLayout when scrolling in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have proposed the design of the main screen of my application with an AppBarLayout of 300dp that will contain the common Toolbar  to the entire application and two sections with a set of actions.

The other area of the screen will be reserved for a list implemented through a view of the type RecyclerView. My goal is to ensure that when the user scrolls down in the list the AppBar will be reduced by 100dp (the last section will disappear smoothly) and also the user image of the application will be hidden and the action menu will appear centered.

Next I expose the state of beginning of the **main screen**:

[image: main_screen]

The root element of the screen is a **CoordinatorLayout** that will contain an **AppBarLayout** and a **RecyclerView** with the **layout_behavior** attribute set to **@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.fragment.home.HomeFragment">

    <!-- App Bar Layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <!-- Include Toolbar -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


        <!-- User Actions Bar -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            style="@style/CommonSection">

            <!-- User Profile Image -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userProfileImage"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"/>


            <!-- Actions -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center">


                <!-- Results -->
                <include layout="@layout/results_menu_item_layout" />
                <!-- Alerts -->
                <include layout="@layout/alerts_menu_item_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
                <!-- Children -->
                <include layout="@layout/children_menu_item_layout" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Children -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            style="@style/CommonSection">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <!-- First Child Image -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/firstChildImage"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"/>


                    <!-- Second Child Image -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/secondChildImage"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"/>


                    <!-- Third Child Image -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thirdChildImage"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addChildBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/plus_circle_solid_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <!-- Alerts List -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/alertsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cyanBrilliant"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to get the following result, but I'm not sure how to properly configure the **scroll flag**:

[image: main screen 2]

Could someone help me achieve this result? Thank you.